# Unable to mount root fs after new kernel compile in VMware

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, compiling, linux-kernel

So, I'm attempting to compile and use the 3.6.2 kernel on my Debian 6 VM (running under Windows 7 in VMware Workstation 9). I've already had several hick ups, but I am slowly getting through them but still not there, yet.

So, I'm running the following (after extracting the file into `/usr/src` and running the commands via `su`)

```
make defconfig
make -j8
make install
make modules_install
update-initramfs -c -k 3.6.2
update-grub
```

I forgot to do the `initramfs` step, which I found from this link [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31112/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-after-new-kernel-compil) but I still got the error, which resulted in me finding this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/445895/failed-to-mount-disk-at-startup). After this, this part of the error below stopped occurring, but the rest was there:

```
W: devtmpfs not available, falling back to tmpfs for /dev
```

Upon the GRUB menu, I edited the root UUID to `/dev/sda1` but it still doesn't find it. I finally followed this [link](http://blog.szlwzl.com/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu-910), but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `make oldconfig` instead, you might be missing the fs driver for your root volume

Comment: Thanks, I found out how to get it working with a bit of research and fiddling. Initially I ran `make localmodconfig` and got that working, so I knew it must've been something I missed. I noticed a few options that were selected in that config that weren't in the default config, so it was a matter of time till I got it to work, luckily coming across the site that I linked helped reduce the time dramatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty then, I found the solution! Booyakasha! :)

After running `lspci` I did a google search for LSI Logic kernel compile (or something to that affect) and came across this [site](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/Host%20Bus%20Adapters/Host%20Bus%20Adapters%20Common%20Files/README_FOR_FC_LinuxMPT_RH3_SLES8_2.06.71.zip.txt). Since it applied to an older kernel version (I assume as it looks different to the settings I have available) I applied the following and got it all working :)

So, assuming you've done as I did and started off with running `make defconfig` run `make menuconfig` and go into `Device Drivers`. Once in there, enable `Fusion MPT device support` and go in there and enable all the modules (Though I don't think you need all of them. I did for now but will tinker and update my answer accordingly after I have done so).

After enabling those modules, save and exit. Modify the `make -j8` part as required. If you're using anything other than GRUB2 the last part will probably be different but hopefully this is generic enough for anyone to use, regardless of distro. So the entire process again, after extracting the kernel to `/usr/src` is:

```
make defconfig
make menuconfig
make -j8
make install
make modules_install
update-initramfs -c -k 3.6.2
update-grub
```

Lastly, you'll need to reinstall your VMware Tools when you're done, so you might wanna remove them first before the whole process.

Cheers guys! :)